# Firebase security rules "hasAny" vs "in" with javascript library is inconsistent

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

This is very counter intuitive but is the javascript library somehow not fully compatible with Firestore security rules?

I would assume there is no connection between security rules syntax and client side requests.

However, Im getting this behavior in a snippet of Firestore security rules:

```
// Works fine in tests with test suite
// Does NOT work with javascript library
request.auth.token.roles[userRole].hasAny([ "admin", "owner" ])

// Works fine in tests with test suite
// Also works fine with javascript library
request.auth.token.roles[userRole] in ([ "admin", "owner" ])
```

**Edit:**
The error on the emulator is very descriptive:

> function not found error: name: [hasany]

So basically it seems that the javascript library isn't compatible with the security rules?

Im using the latest version of everything:

- Emulator (firebase-tools): 10.2.2
- Javascript SDK: 9.6.8

Answer (score 0):

`hasAny` is a construct of the Firestore security rules and does not exist in regular JavaScript arrays.

Your `in` solution in JavaScript is interesting, as I probably would've used `some()` for this.

Comment: Hey Frank! First off, thanks for all your contributions. I might not have been clear enough, those two lines in the snippet are from the security rules. hasAny is a function of List here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List. I access the collection from the javascript SDK by listing the collection and from tests in the backend using the @firebase/testing lib. The problem is that the behavior in both differ.

Comment: I fixed the part where I said the error appeared on the client side. Its actually an error on the emulator when rejecting access to the resource based on the security rules.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it was my fault.

This:

```
request.auth.token.roles[userRole]
```

Returns a `String`. `hasAny` is a function of the `List` interface. It was passing all the tests because in the mocks the value was being mapped as an array. When calling from the client the rules logically failed.